# Sorting a Python list by part of string representing the date

Tags: python, sorting, sortedlist

Considering this list:

```
original_list = ['C:\\\\folder\\Apr2017_VH.img',
                 'C:\\\\folder\\Jan2019_VH.img',
                 'C:\\\\folder\\Nov2017_VH.img',
                 'C:\\\\folder\\Apr2018_VH.img',
                 'C:\\\\folder\\Mar2017_VH.img',
                 'C:\\\\folder\\May2019_VH.img',
                 'C:\\\\folder\\Aug2019_VH.img',
                 'C:\\\\folder\\Jan2020_VH.img',
                 'C:\\\\folder\\Oct2018_VH.img']
```

I need to sort it according to the date:

```
sorted_list = ['C:\\\\folder\\Mar2017_VH.img',
               'C:\\\\folder\\Apr2017_VH.img',
               'C:\\\\folder\\Nov2017_VH.img', 
               'C:\\\\folder\\Apr2018_VH.img',
               'C:\\\\folder\\Oct2018_VH.img', 
               'C:\\\\folder\\Jan2019_VH.img', 
               'C:\\\\folder\\May2019_VH.img',
               'C:\\\\folder\\Aug2019_VH.img', 
               'C:\\\\folder\\Jan2020_VH.img']
```

I tried splitting the string but I couldn't do more than sorting by year, and months by alphabetical order.

Comment: How about creating a list with the months in order so the program could look up which months has the lowest digit and therefore will be the earliest months.

Comment: I've tried but I can't implement it correctly using the sorted() function

Answer (score 4):

Quickly helping before this gets closed:

```
import datetime

def date_from_name(name):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(
        name,
        'C:\\\\folder\\%b%Y_VH.img'
    )

original_list = [
    'C:\\\\folder\\Apr2017_VH.img',
    'C:\\\\folder\\Jan2019_VH.img',
    'C:\\\\folder\\Nov2017_VH.img',
    'C:\\\\folder\\Apr2018_VH.img',
    'C:\\\\folder\\Mar2017_VH.img',
    'C:\\\\folder\\May2019_VH.img',
    'C:\\\\folder\\Aug2019_VH.img',
    'C:\\\\folder\\Jan2020_VH.img',
    'C:\\\\folder\\Oct2018_VH.img'
]

sorted_list = sorted(original_list, key=date_from_name)
print(sorted_list)
```

The special characters for parsing the date are [documented here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `parse` functionality from the `dateutil.parser` module which will be able to parse dates in different formats as well.

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
or_list = ['C:\\\\folder\\Apr2017_VH.img', 'C:\\\\folder\\Jan2019_VH.img', 
           'C:\\\\folder\\Nov2017_VH.img', 'C:\\\\folder\\Apr2018_VH.img', 
           'C:\\\\folder\\Mar2017_VH.img', 'C:\\\\folder\\May2019_VH.img', 
           'C:\\\\folder\\Aug2019_VH.img', 'C:\\\\folder\\Jan2020_VH.img', 
           'C:\\\\folder\\Oct2018_VH.img']

def createdAt(item):
    date = item.split('_VH')[0]
    date = date.split('\\')[-1]
    date = parse(date)
    return date

sortedls = sorted(or_list, key=createdAt)
print(sortedls)
```

Output:

```
['C:\\\\folder\\Mar2017_VH.img', 'C:\\\\folder\\Apr2017_VH.img', 'C:\\\\folder\\Nov2017_VH.img', 'C:\\\\folder\\Apr2018_VH.img', 'C:\\\\folder\\Oct2018_VH.img', 'C:\\\\folder\\Jan2019_VH.img', 'C:\\\\folder\\May2019_VH.img', 'C:\\\\folder\\Aug2019_VH.img', 'C:\\\\folder\\Jan2020_VH.img']
```